# Is there a difference between int *x and int* x in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, naming-conventions, declaration

I'm getting back into my C++ studies, and really trying to understand the basics. Pointers have always given me trouble, and I want to make sure I really get it before I carry on and get confused down the road.

Sadly, I've been stymied at the very outset by an inconsistency in the tutorials I'm reading. Some do pointer declarations this way:

```
int *x
```

and some do it this way:

```
int* x
```

Now the former of the two seems to be by far the most common. Which is upsetting, because the second makes much more sense to me. When I read int *x, I read "Here is an int, and its name is *x", which isn't quite right. But when I read the second, I see "here is an int pointer, and its name is x", which is pretty accurate.

So, before I build my own mental map, is there a functional difference between the two? Am I going to be a leper outcast if I do it the second way?

Thanks.

Comment: odd answer: back in 2002 I had Turbo compiler in C platform in which `int*  x, y;` both x,y was pointer. But in compiler I having in declaration  `int* x,y;` ... `x` is pointer to integer and `y` is `int` !!.. although `int*  x;` and  `int   *x;` both give pointer to integers.

Comment: You've just initiated a potential holywar and a flood of useless paraphrased answers.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: In this regard, C and C++ are same, so when you write `int* x, y`, then `x` is pointer-to-int and `y` is `int`.

Comment: I prefer `int * x;` :p

Comment: @Nawaz actually I am from TOC/formal language background so I would like to share with your... I didn't check C standards but most compilers behaves as you says(*in your answer and comment*) But What might be happen actually   `x * y` is **ambiguous statement** so my older compiler left it erroneous :P

Comment: **http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/**

Comment: `std::add_pointer<int>::type x;` there you go, no spacing issue.

Answer (score 22):

The famous [**Bjarne Stroustrup**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup), notable for the creation and the development of the C++, said ...

> The choice between "int* p;" and "int *p;" is not about right and
>   wrong, but about style and emphasis. C emphasized expressions;
>   declarations were often considered little more than a necessary evil.
>   C++, on the other hand, has a heavy emphasis on types.
>
> A "typical C programmer" writes "int *p;" and explains it "*p is what
>   is the int" emphasizing syntax, and may point to the C (and C++)
>   declaration grammar to argue for the correctness of the style. Indeed,
>   the * binds to the name p in the grammar.
>
> A "typical C++ programmer" writes "int* p;" and explains it "p is a
>   pointer to an int" emphasizing type. Indeed the type of p is int*. I
>   clearly prefer that emphasis and see it as important for using the
>   more advanced parts of C++ well.

So, there's no difference. It is just a code style.

From [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace)

Comment: And, unfortunately, Stroustrup is wrong.

Comment: @cdhowie Why do you think Stroustrup is wrong ?

Comment: @cdhowie In what way? I haven't seen a study into the amount of C++ programmers that do it either way. I feel like I see `int* p` more often than I do `int *p`, and Stroustrup clearly thinks he does too.

Comment: Because Stroustrup prefers a form that is prone to readability errors. `int* x, y;` You will have to spend time trying to figure out what the programmer intended -- did he mean `y` to be a pointer or not?  All we know is: `y` is not a pointer, and the programmer is incompetent because he did not make his intent clear. We don't know if `y` was supposed to be a pointer, and we shouldn't be wasting time trying to figure out what the programmer meant. The `int* x` form is not error-resistant.

Comment: The readability errors arise from declaring more than one variable on a single line. There's no good reason to do so, and it just causes more potential problems than it solves (which is laziness, basically) and it's why most decent coding standards you'll meet when working for real companies disallow it.

Comment: @cdhowie But who writes things like `int* x, y;`?  In general, coding guidelines insist that you don't put two declarations on the same line.  Such things did occur in old C, when you had to declare all of your variables at the top of the block.  For a nested loop, for example, you might write `int i, j, k;`.  In C++, of course (and modern C), each of these declarations would be in the `for` statement.

Comment: @cdhowie I think he'd also say that declaring multiple variables in one declaration was what "typical C programmers" do.

Comment: @sftrabbit In the early days of C, when you had to declare all of your variables at the top of the block, there were contexts where it could be justified.  In C++, never.

Comment: @cdhowie: Don't be ridiculous. How often do you write `int* x, y`, _really_? [There are far more important concerns at work here](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I disagree with the linked rant. Issues of compiler grammar and/or newbie confusion *about the way the language works* are not important to me. What's important to me is maintainability of code, and the most important factor in maintainability is the ability to *correctly and with a minimum of confusion infer the original programmer's intent*.  Only form 3 (in the context of a multi-variable declaration, which admittedly are rare, but I still run across them from time to time) conveys the original programmer's intent with 100% clarity.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm sorry that you don't care about our industry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of course I do -- I prefer forms that make my job easier. The real problem here is not the debate between which form to use, the problem is that the language itself is flawed in this respect.  It would have been better to have pointer and array specifiers be on the type (`int* x, y;` meaning what it looks like and `char[10] x, y;` declaring two arrays). Code should be written to be maintainable, and hence I prefer forms that further that goal. I would rather see newbies writing maintainable, less confusing code.

Comment: @cdhowie: Me too, which is why newbies under my tutelage shall write the type as the type is. `int*` is the type. That's non-confusing, and maintainable. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

To the compiler, they have exactly the same meaning.

Stylistically, there are arguments for and against both.

One argument is that the first version is preferable because the second version:

```
int* x, y, z;
```

implies that `x`, `y` and `z` are all pointers, which they are not (only `x` is).

The first version does not have this problem:

```
int *x, y, z;
```

In other words, since the `*` binds to the variable name and not the type, it makes sense to place it right next to the variable name.

The counter-argument is that one shouldn't mix pointer and non-pointer type in the same declaration. If you don't, the above argument doesn't apply and it makes sense to place the `*` right next to `int` *because it's part of the type*.

Whichever school of thought you decide to subscribe to, you'll encounter both styles in the wild, and more (some people write `int * x`).

Comment: And personally `int *x` is more intuitive.

Comment: I agree with you completely, but I'd also recommend a good ass kicking for anyone who writes either of those 2 lines in real code.

Comment: No, the counter-argument is that this argument is ridiculous. How often do you write `int* x, y`, _really_? [There are far more important concerns at work here](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/). :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Pros and cons aside, I personally think there are more important issues to argue about than where to place the whitespace ;-)

Comment: @NPE: That is also true. But within the scope of arguing about the whitespace... :P

Answer (score 5):

No difference at all.

It is just a matter of style.

I *personally* prefer this:

```
int *x;
```

over this,

```
int* x;
```

Because the latter is less readable when you declare many variables on the same line. For example, see this:

```
int* x, y, z;
```

Here `x` is a pointer to `int`, but are `y` and `z` pointers too? It *looks like* they're pointers, but they are *not*.

Comment: good answer Nawaz long time... read my comment to OP question...

Comment: But no reasonable programmer would write more than one declaration on a line anyway.

Comment: @JamesKanze that is why this question may rise :) Nawaz's suggestion is correct/good  as my experience (I posted to question.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: What is unreasonable about this declaration `point x, y, z;`?

Comment: @Nawaz What's reasonable about it?  Putting it on three lines would be far more readable.  (But I'd want to see the context.  I'm willing to admit that there might be exceptions.  But only when the three types are identical, as when we'd declare `int i, j, k'` in C, before we could put the declarations directly in the `for`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well the only exception I see when you declare pointer and non-pointer on the same line. But that is trap, as it so easy to fall prey into.

Comment: \*yawn\* This again. _It's an edge case_, and [there are far more important concerns at work here](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/).

Comment: @Nawaz But I can't see any reasonable case where you would declare both a pointer and a non-pointer in the same statement.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. I use the `int* x` form because I prefer to keep all of the type grouped together away from the name, but that kind of falls apart with more complex types like `int (*x)[10]`.

Some people prefer `int *x` because you can read it as "dereferencing `x` gives you an `int`". But even that falls apart when you start to use reference types; `int &x` does not mean that taking the address of `x` will give you an `int`.

Another reason that you might prefer `int *x` is because, in terms of the grammar, the `int` is the declaration specifier sequence and the `*x` is the declarator. They are two separate parts of the declaration. This becomes more obvious when you have multiple declarators like `int *x, y;`. It might be easier to see that `y` is not a pointer in this case.

However, many people, like myself, prefer not to declare multiple variables in a single declaration; there isn't exactly much need to in C++. That might be another reason for preferring the `int* x` form.

There's only one rule: be consistent.

Comment: That's not the reason we prefer `int *x`, we prefer it because it's less error-prone when you are declaring multiple variables on the same line.  Prefer forms that are error-resistant.

Comment: @cdhowie Fair point. I added a paragraph on that too!

Comment: @cdhowie But who declares multiple variables on the same line.  That's a misfeature, left over from C, which all good programmers avoid.

Comment: I enjoy how @cdhowie appears to speak for an entire 50% of the programmer population without even consulting them first!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Within the context of the original answer posed here, "we" referred to the same people that sftrabbit referred to in the statement "some people prefer..."  In this context, "we" refers to "those of us who do prefer this form do so because..."  I never implied that I spoke for 50% of the programmer population, and if you inferred that meaning from my statement then you misread it.

Comment: @cdhowie: Nothing that you just said changes the fact that you took it upon yourself to speak for everybody "who do prefer this form".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Very well. I shall therefore amend this statement to have "we" refer to "the many I have encountered during my career who prefer this form."

Comment: @cdhowie: Thank you :) Anyway, `int *x` might be error-resistant _in that one rare edge case_, but it's certainly not misconception-resistant in the way that `int* x` is.

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

No difference.  I've tended to prefer the

```
int* x
```

Due to thinking of 'x' as having type int* .

Answer (score 1):

To the compiler they are the same

But at the same time the difference is readabilty when there are multiple variables

> int *x,y

However this is more misleading

> int* x,y

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same thing.

The former is although preferred. Suppose you want to declare 2 pointers p & q in the same line.

> int* p, q;

This actually means 'p' is a pointer to an int, while 'q' is an int.

The correct syntax would be:

> int* p, *q;

Hence, we include the * in the pointer's name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of style of coding. There's no difference, just a matter of preference as you said yourself.Hope you clear.Enjoy coding

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, in the expression `int * x,y;`  `x` and `y` are names of variables. When these names are declared like this by programmer, it means they have `same type` and `int *` is the 
type.

Comment: Unfortunately, `int* x, y;` means `y` is an `int`, not an `int*`.